# How to generete the Interface (SEI, Service Endpoint Interface) with jaxb2-maven-plugin 2.3.1

Tags: java, maven

I am using the api jaxb2-maven-plugin 2.3.1 to create the class from a WSDL file in a web service SOAP (I am building a server). It work very fine, however I have seen that many people use other plugins to generate the interfaces, of this way the developer in the server only implements the interface and defines the bussines logical in the web service.

Someone knows how can I create the interfaces with the same plugin (jaxb2-maven-plugin 2.3.1). I do not know if that interfaces are only defined in the side of the client. It may be that's why I have not found anything regarding this api.

I am seaching how to do the SEI (Service EndPoint Interface) from  jaxb2-maven-plugin. In the [link](http://www.javajee.com/bottum-up-soap-web-service-development) say:

> The best practice is to have an interface (SEI) that declares the web
>   service operations as its methods, and an implementation (SIB), which
>   defines the methods declared in the interface.

Regards.

Comment: You can customize code generation using JAXB binding, but IMO, it's not worth it. These are DTO, basically POJO, there's no reason to slap an interface in front of them.

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand, I do not know the meaning of IMO. I am beg‌in with a WSDL, It has XSD implemented.

Comment: Ok, let me rephrase my statement. You don't need interfaces.

Comment: Why?. Could you explain me your answer?

Comment: Are you building a client or a server?

Comment: Hi Steve, I am building a server.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [wsimport goal](http://www.mojohaus.org/jaxws-maven-plugin/wsimport-mojo.html) from the [JAX-WS Maven Plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/jaxws-maven-plugin/) instead of the JAXB plugin.

When generating a server you can temporarily set the `genJWS` to true in order to generate server implementation stubs.